# Open new tab after click print buttton in wordpress plugin development

Tags: database, wordpress, url, printing

Hello I new in wordpress plugin development I have a simple plugin working now where I have a form and save the data in wp dtabase this is working properly but I added a new button with id print my intention is after click in it to open new tab with all information from database to print.

Note: I am using .js file to manage the click button request.

Please any examples can help me a lot.

Please share with me a examples how to open new tab after click on button print: Using a .js file to manage the click button I doing a simple wodpress development.